# How can I use OWASP WAF (ESAPIWebApplicationFirewallFilter)?

Tags: java, owasp

I am using 'org.owasp.esapi.waf.ESAPIWebApplicationFirewallFilter' to handle **OWASP Top 10** Vulnerabilities. Is it right way to use this approach? and how do I configure waf-policy.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> This is the main class for the ESAPI Web Application Firewall (WAF).
>   It is a standard J2EE servlet filter that, in different methods,
>   invokes the reading of the configuration file and handles the runtime
>   processing and enforcing of the developer-specified rules. Ideally the
>   filter should be configured to catch all requests (/*) in web.xml. If
>   there are URL segments that need to be extremely fast and don't
>   require any protection, the pattern may be modified with extreme
>   caution.

To use the filter, add `org.owasp.esapi.waf.ESAPIWebApplicationFirewallFilter` in the `web.xml` and add the `jar` file in `project library.`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ESAPI-WAF</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.owasp.esapi.waf.ESAPIWebApplicationFirewallFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Comment: how do I create waf-policy (developer-specified rules) file ? please share example and complete description.